# Error 'Missing: SyncTestZoneSpec' during karma test with angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

First thing first : my project is totally sane on branch `/develop` with test passing and all.

I created a branch to clean `imports` and use aliases instead of `../../../../` each time I have to access classes. I added it into `tsconfig.json` :

```
"baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "app/*"
      ],
      "@core/*": [
        "app/core/*"
      ],
      "@common/*": [
        "app/common/*"
      ],
      "@models/*": [
        "app/models/*"
      ],
      "@env/*": [
        "environments/*"
      ],
      "@assets/*": [
        "assets/*"
      ]
    }
```

I just finished but when executing the test with simple `npm run test` which do something like thiis is think `karma start ./karma.conf.js --log-level error` I get this error :

```
HeadlessChrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Missing: SyncTestZoneSpec
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:270128
```

All I have changed is what I told above, what is this error telling me ?

---

EDIT : Correction with github links

Corrected this issue by updating the zone.js version to 0.8.26 and replaced the imports in test.ts by only one line :

`import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';`

But now I get this error for all tests :

```
HeadlessChrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10.0.0) SomeService #getCurrentUser should return user object FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined
            at resetFakeAsyncZone node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:308:1)
            at Object.<anonymous> node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:1015:1)
            at ZoneQueueRunner.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.jasmine.QueueRunner.ZoneQueueRunner.execute node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:437:1)
HeadlessChrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 120 of 120 (120 FAILED) ERROR (4.725 secs / 4.633 secs)
```

[Relatedd issue on github](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1058#issuecomment-399513316) but no solution for now.

The content of my `test.ts` :

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare const __karma__: any;
declare const require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

Comment: Checked this? https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1058

Comment: Already checked it but not concluent

Comment: can you post your tests.ts?

Comment: @An-droid https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/767 this might help

Comment: I updated zone.js to version 0.8.26 so import order doess not impact my issue. I'll post my test.ts for you to see

Comment: can you please have a look on the order of the modules. check this: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/767

Comment: As said in my previous comment, by updating the version I got ride of the module order issue :) also see the EDIT of my question

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `zone-testing` import up to be one of the first imports like this:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from 
'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
```

Taken from this bug report: [All tests failed if order of imports is changed in test.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9641)